# yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss - What is the meaning of 'T' here?

Tags: java, .net, datetime

What is the meaning of `T` in this datetime pattern ?

`yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss  2011-06-14T04:12:36`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It just shows the start of the **Time** component in a standard ISO 8601 date time string. Wikipedia has a [detailed page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) about this standard format.

Comment: Is there any  functions i can use to generate that format of time in JavaScript ?

Comment: It's completely off topic for this question but yes [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) will output a datetime in this format in JavaScript

Answer (score 9):

In ISO 8601 (UTC) T is used to designate the Time component.
See "Combined date and time representations" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations

Find out about UTC here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time.

Answer (score 6):

[T] is time designator for [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of `<date>T<time>`.

Answer (score 5):

it means "Time". this has been asked and answered a lot. see http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime.html

Answer (score 4):

It's from [ISO 8601](http://dotat.at/tmp/ISO_8601-2004_E.pdf) which specifies a standard timestamp format:

> The character [T] shall be used as time designator to indicate the start of the representation of the time of day component in these expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Without some context, that's hard to answer.

However, according to the SimpleDateFormat [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) 'T' is meaningless i.e. just a string literal.

This is supported by the fact the T is visible in your output string. Perhaps it means time?