# How do I convert timestamp string to milliseconds?

Tags: android, time

How can i convert this time and date which coming from json data in android to milliseconds properly ??

```
2013-09-19T03:27:23+01:00
```

and what's the meaning of **T** ??

Comment: check this [So](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340794/yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-what-is-the-meaning-of-t-here)

Comment: The meaning of 'T': Google for [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

not sure about `and what's the meaning of T ??` but you can use following code to get milliseconds.

```
String dateString="2013-09-19T03:27:23+01:00";
        if (dateString != null) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            Date testDate = null;
            try {
                testDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Milliseconds==" + testDate.getTime());

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
String myDate = new String("your date");
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(myDate);
date.getTime();
```